# Visual C#/WinForms Date and Time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

Hello I want to create a clock in visual c#. Ive tried using the date time picker.

Yea. It gets the current time. But I want to have it auto updated just like a real clock so that the user can have a guide of the current date and time. thanks....

By the way its a windows form and I am using visual studio 2010

Comment: `DateTimePicker` control is not designed to act as a real-time clock, you can use `Now()` method from `DateTime` class to get current date and time and also you can use `DateTime` object fields to get `Hour`, `Minute`, `Seconds`, ... individually. You can then design your custom control or just get the current time value and display it in a `Label` control for example.

Comment: I don't get the idea.  DateTimePicker is something you use to get a time *other* than the current time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use "Timer" and do some operations to refresh time.
You can get more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

Comment: You don't want to use a timer for this, since the timing isn't guaranteed.

Comment: Timing of nothing is guaranteed, unless you use a special real-time OS. Timer is the right tool for this job.

Comment: +1 He should use `Timer` AND readjust the `Interval` each time to compensate.

Answer (score 1):

whit the timer you can do this.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }
```

Regards

Comment: Carmelo what about: DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); ?

Comment: Hy Davide , you're right, I fix now and much more functional, thanks.

Comment: Hy Davide, thanks again, quickly, and unfortunately sometimes the bad advisor.
 Hello and thanks again.